# When to use implicit or explicit code blocks

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand when one should code blocks implicitly or explicitly. Given the following code blocks:

- Implicit

  ```
  def two_times_implicit 
    return "No block" unless block_given? 
    yield 
    yield 
  end

  puts two_times_implicit { print "Hello "}
  puts two_times_implicit
  ```
- Explicit

  ```
  def two_times_explicit (&i_am_a_block) 
    return "No block" if i_am_a_block.nil? 
    i_am_a_block.call 
    i_am_a_block.call 
  end 

  puts two_times_explicit { puts "Hello"}
  puts two_times_explicit
  ```

Is it preferable to code using one over the other? Is there a standard practice and are there instances where one would work better or differently than the other and where one would not work at all?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) *"If you are only going to call the block and will not otherwise manipulate it or send it to another method using yield without an explicit block parameter is preferred."*

Comment: it's mostly just a personal stylistic preference. You NEED to use the explicit `&block` if you want to store the block in a variable or pass it to a method. Otherwise, most people use implicit (which is faster), but I sometimes still prefer explicit for clarity (and the performance difference is unlikely to matter in most cases).

Answer (score 6):

Receiving a block via `&` creates a new proc object out of the block, so from the point of view of efficiency, it is better not to use it. However, using `&` generally makes it easier to define methods that may or may not take a block, and using `&`, you can also handle blocks together with arguments, so it is preferred by many.

Comment: Also, you have to use `&block` if you want to pass it around.

Comment: Could you elaborate "makes it easier to define methods that may or may not take a block" and "you can also handle blocks together with arguments"?

Comment: You don't need the explicit version to handle blocks together with arguments, or to define a method that may or may not take a block. Implicit works fine in both cases. The only time you NEED explicit is if you want to save the block in a variable or pass it to another method.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, according to one [very interesting read](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.2.0/symbols/Proc/yield?#annotation=4087638&line=711&hn=1), second variant is 439% slower ([related thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9118176) on HackerNews).

TL;DR: Creating and passing a block via `yield` is a highly optimized common case in MRI, which is handled by dedicated C function in interpreter, while passing `&block` is implemented differently and has a big overhead of creating new environment and creating `Proc` itself on every call.

Summing up, use `&block` only if you need passing it further (for example, to a next function), or manipulate it somehow in other way. Otherwise, use `yield`, since it's way faster.